# Comparing a floating point to one or zero with Wfloat-equal option

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, compare, clang

I'm somewhat familiar with the issues around performing floating point equality comparisons in code.

Currently the code base I'm compiling on **(GCC, Clang)** have the following option enabled: **-Wfloat-equal**

And in the code base there's the following example comparison:

```
template <typename FloatType>
void foo(FloatType v) {
  if (v == FloatType(1)) {
   ...
  }
  else if (v == FloatType(0)) {
   ....
  }
}
```

The foo function is invoked as follows:

```
double d = 123.98;
float f = 123.98f;

foo(d);
foo(f);
```

Given the special case of 1 and 0 which each have exact representations in floating points *(double, float)* and where the code is clearly after an exact equality and not something that is close by some minor difference -

Is there a way to rewrite the code such that it will not raise the associated **Wfloat-equal** diagnostic and will also be portable and support both float and double types?

Comment: You could use GCC's `#pragma GCC diagnostic push/pop/ignored` to disable the diagnostic for just those lines.

Comment: you can always use `memcmp`

Comment: @VTT when you say memcmp, do you mean to have a separate variable for the values 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes, you will need a separate (probably const) 1 an 0 variables to be able to apply `memcmp` however compiler might be smart enough to optimize it all away and leave just a straight comparison without taking addresses and invoking `memcmp`.

Comment: Why are you passing `-Wfloat-equal` to the compiler then?

Comment: If you use memcmp, remember that 0 can be represented by two different bit patterns.

Comment: Would std::equal_to work?
 It is a standard header, so GCC may not give the warning (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to)

Comment: @MarcGlisse  it's an option that is being used as part of the build process - I don't have any control over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `std::equal_to`. As far as GCC is concerned it will disable a whole bunch of checks when processing the system headers including the `float-equal`

```
template <typename FloatType>
void foo(FloatType v) {
  if (std::equal_to<FloatType>()(v,FloatType(1))) {
   ...
  }
  else if (std::equal_to<FloatType>()(v,FloatType(0))) {
   ....
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is more of a bug (that library code directly triggered by the user does not raise warnings) than an intended way to silence this type of warning. A easier-to-understand way would be to write a `float_equal_no_warning` function or similar.